# jQuery not changing width

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code, I feel like I have tried everything but nothing is affecting the canvas. I have been researching for the last hour and I tried just plain javascript, but for some reason the canvas is not changing. This same code works for an iframe on a different page.

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#canvas").attr('width', 800);
    });
</script>
```

What I want to do is set the width equal to the window size minus 100 px, but right now I have it set as 800 so I can try to figure out why this is not working.

Comment: `$("#canvas").attr('width', 800);` ?

Comment: that does not work either

Comment: You have included jQuery somewhere right? The code works fine for me... `using $("#canvas").attr('width,800);` instead of `$("canvas").width(800)`. (This second command did resize the canvas, it just also maintained the original aspect ratio, so the resized canvas was 800 by 800).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to redraw the canvas once you've resized it. First, grab the 2d context with getContext('2d'), then call the necessary functions on the context, most likely strokeRect()

```
var myCanvas = $('#canvas').attr('width',800);
var myContext = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
myContext.strokeRect(0,0,myCanvas.attr('width'),myCanvas.attr('height'));
```

I think that's right, but there could be some code errors, hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Off-topic, is your username related to _Zarathustra_?

Comment: Thanks, all I had to do was put it before the chart was drawn by the script

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
#canvas {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#canvas").css('width','800px');
    });
</script>
```